# Making a circle intersect 3 points

Tags: geometry

Current I have a circle which intersects $ (\pm w,0) $ ([link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8vz8w9kd8b)):

$$
\left(y+\sqrt{r^{2}-w^{2}}\right)^{2}+x^{2}=r^{2} \{w<r\}
$$

[image]

---

I want to further restrict this to intersecting some point $ (0,b) \{b>0\}$ (e.g. $(0,200)$).

And further, that given some $f(c,...)=b$ then $ f(c+1,...)=f(c,...)+1 $. Which is to say, by making some change to a variable (in this example $c$) in the circle equation, we see a change in $b$ which is constant (this example being $1$).

My initial approach was trying to use the equation $ (y+w)^2+x^2=(r+v)^2 $ ([link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kxxykf2o9r)) but I couldn't get this to lead anywhere.

---

Apologies if my question is missing something please drop a comment and I'll make any changes.

Comment: You cannot guarantee any circle will go through four arbitrary points.  Just think of a triangle with a point in its interior, for example.

Comment: For three non-collinear points $A$, $B$ and $C$, construct the line segments $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{BC}$. The two bisectors of those segments will intersect at the center of the circle containing those three points.

Comment: *Any* three non-collinear points determine a *single* circle.  If you also want to further restrict the circle to go through some fourth point, it just won't do it, except by sheer "luck".

Comment: @DavidG.Stork If I understand correctly, the OP is not asking for the circle to pass through 4 points. He's asking for a way to parametrize the family of circles passing through $(\pm w,0)$ such that the intersection of the circle with $y$ axis, $(0,b)$ varies linearly with the parameter.

Comment: @bob.sacamento If I understand correctly, the OP is not asking for the circle to pass through 4 points. He's asking for a way to parametrize the family of circles passing through $(\pm w,0)$ such that the intersection of the circle with $y$ axis, $(0,b)$ varies linearly with the parameter.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I understand this, perhaps I have not given a neccessary limit? For example, for $y+\sqrt{vr^2-w}^2+x^2=ar^2$ values of $w$ and $v$ can be given such that this circle intersects (\pm w,0) and (0,200) for instance, I understand there is both a limit in $w$  in that $w<r$ and a limit in $0<v<t$ (I'm not sure what $t$ is). So it doesn't work with any cirlce, but it does work within the limits.

Comment: @jjagmath Yes that seems an accurate description of what I'm trying to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood properly what you exactly want. However please comment on answer given below:

All circles pass through *fixed* points $ (\pm w,0)$ on x-axis. The third point is *variable*.

From the constraint
$$ w^2= r^2-k^2, $$

for a given $k$, radius r is required to be calculated and vice versa. All their centers lie on $y-$ axis.

[image]

A few cases are shown with $ ( k = \pm 3, \pm 5)$

They are called *Co-axal Circles* with the property $ OA\cdot OB = w^2,$ a constant, negative power of the set of these circles.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for but close enough, from this [I managed to solve my issue](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ldvbsiv8x6).

Comment: Yes that's it,  more or less.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you have your circle $\left(y+\sqrt{r^{2}-w^{2}}\right)^{2}+x^{2}=r^{2} \{w<r\}$.
You now want the circle to reach the point $P=(0,b)$ while it still touches $(\pm w,0)$ right?

The circle needs to grow bigger if the tip is already above $P$ and shrink down if the tip is below. We do not know the exact value right now but we know that there has to be a factor - let's call it $a$ to stretch the radius as we move the circle up- or downwards some distance $d$.

The problem should be closed to solved when you can move the circle up and down without chaning the intersection with the x-axis.
I will try and find a way to do that.

Comment: `The circle needs to grow bigger if the tip is already above P and shrink down if the tip is below.` In my current approach ${0<b}$, I'm not certain this is fundemental to the problem, but worth noting in this case, the circle should shrink if the tip is above $P$ and grow if the tip is below $P$ (defining the tip as the point on the circle with the largest positive $y$ value)).

Comment: @JonathanWoollett-light If we move the circle downwards (negative y direction) we need to move the center of the circle downwards and to not change the intersections with the x-axis we need to grow it. I already did this on https://www.desmos.com/calculator/can2w74h3n but I don't know how to get the $w$ in properly...

Comment: also the $b$ on the desmos plot moves the center not the point with the highest positive y value (I called it the tip of the circle).